# Playing Uploaded Videos or embed youtube videos

Tags: html, video, youtube

I'm creating a Content Management System that allows the content manager to upload videos to the server.  There will be a list of pages and each one will have a video on it.  Each video should then be able to be played by the content observer.

Problem: I can get some videos to play, but I cannot get all of them to play and I don't know why.  **How do I force the content manager to upload only videos that work or convert videos that do not work?**  I've used embed, object, iframes, and videos tags, but I can't to get any of them to work all the time. This link is what I have tried. http://ww.w3schools.com/html/html_videos.asp

Alternative Solution: Just make the content manager upload videos to youtube, then put the embed code in the database and call for it when you need it.  This works but the code does not validate when you do this which is bad for SEO.  Also, if the content manager does not do it correctly he could be advertising for the competition because the video can show links to other videos when it is done.

Comment: If your page doesn't validate it isn't bad for SEO. Valid SEO is **not** a ranking factor.

Comment: Update: Youtube now uses iframes, which might be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard. In our CMS you need verify the content, probably in a async procedure, and reject the video if there is something wrong. The most important is choose a good set of formats and codecs (and other characteristics like Frames Per Second, Audio Bitrate, etc) and make this "contract" something very explicit. ffmpeg with -i option can identify the video, extension, codec, length, aspect-ratio, etc.

You also try to convert from any format to one good format like mp4 h264 with 360p.